# Run through multiple data types using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Background Info**

Hi, im not sure if its possible however Im trying to work out a way that run through a bunch of data-types and change text based on it. I know you can do it by writing every data-type and then editing the related class. However I plan to have loads of data-types and therefore looking for a time saving solution.

So my plan is to have lots of information linked to a certain div, this is so when click it can update a information section based on the data. All of the data-types will have the same data-test-

```
<div class="box" data-test-1="1.1" data-test-2="1.2" data-test-3="1.3"></div>
<div class="box" data-test-1="2.1" data-test-2="2.2" data-test-3="2.3"></div>
<div class="box" data-test-1="3.1" data-test-2="3.2" data-test-3="3.3"></div>
```

**The question**

Is the away I can use jQuery to run through all of the data-test-"" when the box is clicked and then link them to a match ID.

**Simplified version -** https://jsfiddle.net/gaLLms9b/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** If you're only interested that the data is in the format of:

> data-`static`-(mustbeanumber)

See answer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36440209/2825245).

Otherwise you can use this one.

You can loop through all the elements and match for `data-test-`. In that way you can add more attributes and it will still work. Here is an working example.

```js
$(".box").click(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
    if (this.specified) {
      if (this.name.indexOf('data-test-')>-1) {
        $('#' + this.name).html(this.value);
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-test-1="1.1" data-test-2="1.2" data-test-3="1.3"></div>

<div class="box" data-test-1="2.1" data-test-2="2.2" data-test-3="2.3"></div>

<div class="box" data-test-1="3.1" data-test-2="3.2" data-test-3="3.3"></div>

<p id="data-test-1">Click on the boxes to change information</p>
<p id="data-test-2">Infor 2</p>
<p id="data-test-3">Infor 3</p>
```

Comment: Works perfectly and a lot simpler to understand, thank you

Comment: this will match elements data like `data-test-this`

Comment: @MattHammond it was just a note for future visitors to this question and answers if their need is to be more precise about the data-* selector.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Okey, I wish I could mark both of your answers as both work perfectly!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I added a note above my answer for better visibility for future visitors.

Comment: @Roy thanks but the notice is quite misleading since I provided both examples for handling `data-static-variable` and `data-static-(mustbeanumber)`

Comment: Cause the `otherwise use this one` is totally incorrect.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Now check.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop all your dataset properties,
once you match that the dataset is in this format:

```
^     // start of string
test- // has "test-"
\d+   // one or more numbers
$     // end of string
```

if you're only interested that the data is in the format of:

> data-`static-`*variable*

than you can simply use this **RegExp**: `/^static-/`

You can use the actual data-`key` and `val` like:

```js
$(".box").click(function() {
  $.each(this.dataset, function(key, val) {
    if(/^test-\d+$/.test( key )){ // make sure the data is "test-N(N..)"
      $("#data-"+ key).html( val );
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" data-foo="bar" data-test-1="1.1" data-test-2="1.2" data-test-3="1.3"></div>
<div class="box" data-test-1="2.1" data-test-2="2.2" data-test-3="2.3"></div>
<div class="box" data-test-1="3.1" data-test-2="3.2" data-test-3="3.3"></div>

<p id="data-test-1">Click on the boxes to change information</p>
<p id="data-test-2">Infor 2</p>
<p id="data-test-3">Infor 3</p>
<p id="data-foo">This should be left unchanged cause does 
    not matches the needed data test-N(N..) format </p>
```

Comment: Great answer, work perfectly! However I am so confused by it ;) But thank you

Comment: @MattHammond yeh it's a bit strange cause there's that method called `.test()` that matches a string and by coincidence you also have a string with `test-` so too much confusing `test`s :) Expanded my answer by using `static` and `variable` terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Element.dataset` , `for..in` loop . Interestingly, both `$(this).data("test-1")` and  `$(this).data("test1")` return `undefined` ?

```
$(".box").click(function() {
  var data = this.dataset;
  for (var prop in data) {
    $("#data-" + prop).html(data[prop])
  }
})
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gaLLms9b/3/

Comment: this will also search for `#data-foo` and set the value to `bar` is the `data-foo="bar"` was present

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Not following ? Can you describe what you mean in `javascript` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Could point, this could prove to be problematic when working for multiple data types! However great answer if the situation was simpler

Comment: @MattHammond better prevent than cure.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Do you mean adding requirement to the original Question by including `data-foo="bar"` at `html` ? Set the value to `bar` where ? Why would you include attributes at `html` where not present at original Question? If requirement was to change existing `html`, all of the `data-test-*` attributes could be set at single attribute, instead of multiple `data-*` attributes.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  _"and set the value to `bar` is the `data-foo="bar"` was present"_ Set the value to `bar` where ?

Answer (score 0):

`.data()` apparently does not recognize digits separated by `-` as a valid property name.

You could adjust `html` to set each `data-*` as an object containing property names corresponding to `id` of elements, use `$.each()` to iterate property names, values and set `.html()` on matched element that passed `.is()` condition at `if`

html

```
<div class="box" 
  data-test='{"test":1.1,"test-2":1.2,"test-3":1.3}' 
  data-other='{"other-1":7.0}'></div>

<div class="box" 
  data-test='{"test-1":2.1,"test-2":2.2,"test-3":2.3}'></div>

<div class="box" 
  data-test='{"test-1":3.1,"test-2":2.2,"test-3":2.3}'></div>

<p id="data-test-1">Click on the boxes to change information</p>
<p id="data-test-2">Infor 2</p>
<p id="data-test-3">Infor 3</p>
<p id="data-other-1">Infor 3</p>
```

javascript

```
$(".box").click(function() {
  $.each($(this).data(), function(prop, value) {
    $.each(value, function(key, val) {
      var el = $("#data-" + key);
      if (el.is("*")) el.html(val)
    })
  })
})
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gaLLms9b/5/